# Tailwind CSS — How do I reference another value defined in my theme in the config file?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, tailwind-css, commonjs

I am trying to set up a custom Tailwind CSS theme in the `tailwind.config.js` file with a color palette that consists of two groups of color: *core* and *derived* colors.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      core: {
        neutral: {
          // ...
          500: '#63727D'
        }
      },
      derived: {
        // ...
        text: {
          muted: // Here I want to reference a theme.colors.core.neutral.500 value, #63727D.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure referencing out, though. What I've tried so far was:

1. **Reading a [TailwindCSS documentation for theme configuration and referencing other values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#referencing-other-values)**. The closest thing to what I wanted to achieve was the "You can't use functions for individual values" example. But I couldn't extract any solution for me out of that.
2. **Using a getter.** I coulnd't get this to work, as the color of the text is not on the same level in my object's hierarchy as the neutral.500 color, and setting it to `get muted() { return this.theme.colors.core.neutral[500] }` didn't work.
3. **Defining my core color values in a separate object.** While this worked *technically*, I found that to be a rather short-sighted solution, as I can soon find myself in a need of referencing/derived core color values between each other, too.

Unless I should adopt a whole different way of thinking about it, my ideal solution would be to keep all my color definitions within the `module.exports` with the ability to cross-reference values inside.

Comment: You are trying to reference values before the object is created. Instead, you can opt for using CSS variables. This will move the reading of the variables into your actual CSS instead of the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

## Preface

I know this is an old question but I stumbled upon it while searching for the answer myself. I'm posting the solution I used so that anyone in the future may learn from it.

## Solution

---

### Using Getters

I was able to solve this my issue by using using an object getter. Note that I did not define parent objects for `core` and `derived` as the color would show up in tailwind as `text-core-neutral-500` and `text-derived-text-muted`.

Here is my config with the color values defined as properties of the top level `colors` object:

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        colors: {
            neutral: {
                500: '#63727D',
            },
            get muted() {
                return this.neutral[500];
            },
        },
    },
};
```

### Using Smaller Objects

However, as stated in the question above, the issue OP is having is due to having nested objects, so `this` refers to the closest scoped object which is the `text` object.

We can get around this by breaking apart the `colors` object into smaller objects that are defined separately. Now we are able to reference the `core` object from within the `derived` object. Then we simple add both the `core` and `derived` objects as properties on the `color` object.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```js
const core = {
    neutral: {
        // ...
        500: '#63727D',
    },
};

const derived = {
    // ...
    text: {
        muted: core.neutral[500],
    },
};

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        colors: {
            core,
            derived,
        },
    },
};
```